# Scope Errors with Switch statement

Tags: c++, scope, switch-statement, declaration

when I am doing this switch statement I am getting this error:error: ‘Ptr’ was not declared in this scope. I do not understand why this is happening since I am dynamically allocating Ptr. If I remove the curly braces I get the error: ‘Ptr’ has a previous declaration as ‘(//Class Name)* Ptr’. How do I fix this? Thanks.

```
switch(i){
    case 0:{
        Class0* Ptr = new Class0;
    }
    case 1:{
        Class1* Ptr = new Class1;
        break;
    }
    case 2:{
        Class2* Ptr = new Class2;
        break;
    }
    case 3:{
        Class3* Ptr = new Class3;
        break;
    }
    case 4:{
        Class4* Ptr = new Class4;
        break;
    }
    case 5:{
        Class5* Ptr = new Class5;
        break;
    }
}
myMap["key"] = Ptr;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common scoping error

```
{
  int j =1;
}
cout<<j<<endl;
```

The value of j is only accessible inside the brackets and not outside it i.e. the cout statement will give an error. 
You can use the following workaround for your task.

```
switch(i){
case 0:{
    Class0* Ptr = new Class0;
    myMap["key"] = Ptr;
    break;
}
case 1:{
    Class1* Ptr = new Class1;
    myMap["key"] = Ptr;
    break;
}
case 2:{
    Class2* Ptr = new Class2; myMap["key"] = Ptr;
    break;
}
case 3:{
    Class3* Ptr = new Class3;  myMap["key"] = Ptr;
    break;
}
case 4:{
    Class4* Ptr = new Class4;  myMap["key"] = Ptr;
    break;
}
case 5:{
    Class5* Ptr = new Class5;  myMap["key"] = Ptr;
    break;
}
}
```